# AttributeError: 'Subject' object has no attribute 'file' when upload file in Django

Tags: python, django, imagehash

i 'm trying tp upload a file in Django use ImageField. I want to hash this img before upload (using ImageHash), and save the image with the hashed file name. Below is my code, can you helo me fix this?

models.py

```
 from utils import hash_image
 ...
 class: Subject(models.Model):
     photo = models.ImageField(upload_to=hash_image)
 ...
```

utils

```
    def hash_image(instance, filename):
        instance.file.open()
        ext = os.path.splitext(filename)[1]
        image_hash = ''
        image_hash = str(imagehash.average_hash(instance.file)) + '.' + ext
        return image_hash
```

Error:

```
line 34, in hash_image
        instance.file.open()
    AttributeError: 'Subject' object has no attribute 'file'
```

Comment: Instance is your model instance, not the photo field.

Comment: @Melvyn thank for your information, what should i to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically need something [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41906536/1600649). And to address your error: your file is `instance.photo` not `instance.file`.

But I'm not sure it can work with imagehash, because [UploadedFile](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/files/uploads/#django.core.files.uploadedfile.UploadedFile) is not a file-like object. In particular [Image.Open](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.open) requires that the object implements `seek()` and UploadedFile does not do this. I don't see a way to construct an Image object here that imagehash will be able to use, but maybe somebody else can.

Comment: Based on your answer, I have fixed it as follows:
```img = Image.open(instance.photo)
    image_hash = str(imagehash.average_hash(img))``` 
Luckily, it worked

Comment: Wow, then I guess it doesn't use `seek()` for this workload. :D